# How to define and get/put the values in Jenkinsfile groovy map

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have this Jenkinsfile below. I am trying to get the key of a map but I am getting `"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'get' found among steps"`. Can someone help me to resolve this?

```
def country_capital = {
    [Australia : [best: 'xx1', good: 'xx2', bad: 'xx3'],
    America : [best: 'yy1', good: 'yy2', bad: 'yy3']]
}

pipeline {
    agent any    
    stages {
        stage('Test Map') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo country_capital.get('Australia')['best']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value using this way

```groovy
def country_capital = [
    Australia: [
        best: 'xx1',
        good: 'xx2',
        bad: 'xx3'
    ],
    America: [
        best: 'yy1',
        good: 'yy2',
        bad: 'yy3'
    ]
]

pipeline {
    agent any    
    stages {
        stage('Test Map') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo country_capital['Australia'].best
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Output
xx1
```

Comment: That is working but it seems very complex. I know I can get the value using get method. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

For the above example one can also do

```
country_capital.each { capital_key, capital_value ->
try {
  echo "Testing ${capital_value.best}..."
}
catch(ex){
  echo "Test failed: ${capital_value.bad}"                    }
}
```